# SQL SSIS 2016 / Visual Studio 2015 Deployment package issues

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016

I am having an issue with deploying a SSIS package. When the package is executed in Visual Studio 2015 it completes with no issues. However when the package is deployed to my SQL server 2016 the characters `å`, `ø`, `æ` are changed to something else and resulting in error. In this this case am I doing a SELECT statement where one of the colum names is `IndkøbskategoriNavn`.

[image: The error I get when run the job]

I have tried to change `IndkøbskategoriNavn AS IndkoebskategoriNavn` (plus the other column names that have `ø`) but the `ø` is still in the query and I can't change the column name.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you already try to select [IndkøbskategoriNavn] instead of IndkøbskategoriNavn?

Comment: Right click your data flow task and go into the advanced editor to make sure the inputs and outputs match up as sometimes they don't update and you have to change them manually here.

Comment: The "Invalid Column Name" error message suggests that the column does not exist in the table.  Could you double check your configuration on the server and make sure the listed columns exist in the table?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz Yes i have double checked and i have run the Query in SQL management and it works.

Comment: @Tyron78 Yes its actually the way i run the query

Comment: @JonathanPorter I have checked and the output is correct also the mapping.

Comment: Then another possibility might be to use aliases in SSIS. You can rename the columns in the flow. Even if SSMS is able to handle these names, maybe SSIS got problems with the chars...

Comment: I ran a test in SSIS using that column name and it worked fine.  I was thinking that the configuration may differ on the server.  Maybe it is pointing to a different version of the database.